# how determine if object has child of certain element?

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple function, which I want to work only if selected object has child of certain type - in this case if it has ul nested.

I have tried with this:

```
var onMouseOver = function() {
 if (this.getElementsByTagName('ul') > 0);{
   console.log('entered');
 }
}
```

and this:

```
var onMouseOver = function() {
 if (this.querySelector('ul') != null);{
   console.log('enter');
 }
}
```

but it doesn't help - function still launches, even when it returnes 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at the length property of those selectors.

```js
var onMouseOver = function() {
 if (this.querySelectorAll('ul').length > 0);{
   console.log('enter');
 }
}
```

or

```js
var onMouseOver = function() {
 if (this.getElementsByTagName('ul').length > 0);{
   console.log('entered');
 }
}
```

Comment: I have tried both of these versions, but it still won't work. 

Example: in html I have elements nested [like this](http://pastebin.com/bKHPnvDb). For <li>Element 3</li> function should not work, but it still does.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :)

```js
function ok(obj) {
  var l = obj.children.length;

  for (var i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
    if (obj.children[i].tagName == "UL") {
      var c = obj.children[i].children[0];
      alert("child id is :-" + c.tagName);
      alert("child id is :-" + c.id);
      alert("child value  is :-" + c.innerHTML);
      break;
    }

  }
}
```

```css
#child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="Parent" onmouseover="ok(this)">Find Child ? mouse over me
    <p id="child">I'm Child</p>
    <ul>
      <li id="list">hello</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I need - I am looking for something that will work only, if child/children are a certain tags; this case I need function to work only if there are ul's nested.

Comment: Thank you! It's a bit longer than I thought it would be, but works. :)